# Infinispan - is there no option to delete a cache?

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching, distributed-system, infinispan

Sorry, if this question is way too simple, but I am searching the docs for two days but I am not able to find a method that can delete a complete cache. (not just the key-value pairs, but the cache also).
I am working in spring boot and infinispan, so if anyone has any idea regarding this, please share.
EDIT: Please tell me a method in java/spring over hot rod. (Remote Cache Manager)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RemoteCacheManager's administration API has a `removeCache()` method:

```
remoteCacheManager.administration().removeCache(cacheName);
```

https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/13.0/apidocs/org/infinispan/client/hotrod/RemoteCacheManagerAdmin.html#removeCache(java.lang.String)

Comment: Hi @Tristan, can you please help with one more question that I have posted?

Answer (score 1):

Kindly look here: https://infinispan.org/docs/dev/titles/cli/cli.html

According to it, you can clear an entire cache via the following command type:

```
[//containers/default]> clearcache mycache
```

You can also drop a cache via

```
[//containers/default]> drop cache mycache
```

Comment: @HardikSomani so you have a local environment and a remote environment and you intend to remove the cache of the remote environment using your local environment?

Comment: @HardikSomani I'm not aware of such a method, but you can execute a command-line command pretty easily in Java, so you can execute the CLI commands I have in my answer pretty easily, see: https://dzone.com/articles/execute-shell-command-java

Comment: @HardikSomani you could also write a very simple bash script that connects to your server via ssh and runs the cache clear. Or you could implement this as a method, deploy on your environments and create a UI where a button click would trigger the cache clear method/CLI execution.